# Linting of the source code in CI pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, lint

We would like to implement linting of source code stage to our CI, what are the best tools and best practices to follow to lint our source in CI pipeline as code ?
Did a couple of research found SonarQube to be useful, but it does more of static code analysis than providing the structural/stylic errors that's needed(correct me if i'm wrong), basically linting. Looking for tools which would ensure code style and consistency of code formatting standards, found "Scalastyle - Scala style checker" which can be intergrated with Sonarqube, looking for linting Scala and Java code, is there any tool that could fit in along a CI pipeline ?

Comment: We do it by issuing `sh "make lint"` inside linting stage. People who want to lint on their machine can just use `make lint`.

Comment: @MaratC Thanks for your reply, i haven't got much documentations on it, got few examples on makefile for go programming, can it be used for any programming language cause we need to lint java, scala and js source code, if there is any documentations, please post it, Thanks again !

Answer (score -2):

This is a bad idea. The place for linting is in the UI of your code editor and/or at pre-commit stage. You want to lint your code before it gets checked-in and shared.